# Из набора точек geography построить линию

Tags: sql-server

В столбце с типом *geography* хранятся координаты точки. Мне нужно выбрать точки из этого столбца отвечающие заданным критериям и создать из них линию в переменной с типом *geography*.

Решение на ум приходит только собрать из них строку и воспользоваться `geography::STLineFromText()`, но вероятно есть правильное и простое решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что нет простого решения. Есть агрегирующие функции `geography::CollectionAggregate()` и `geography::UnionAggregate()`, но они не позволяют задать порядок следования точек, что важно для линии.

Можно через текст. В этом случае, думаю, что лучше использовать `ToString()`, из которого вырезать подстроку, а не `cast` от `Lat` и `Long`, чтобы не зависеть от символа десятичного разделителя. Затем склеивать всё в линию.

Также можно через *Gml* и *WKB*.

Пусть, например, `@Points` олицетворяет отобранные нами точки с номерами их следования:

```
declare @Points table (num int, point geography);

declare @cnt int = 1000;
with tally as (select top (@cnt + 1) N = row_number() over (order by @@spid) from sys.all_columns)
insert into @Points (num, point)
select
    N, geography::Point(
        (50 + 10 * sin(26 * t)) * sin(2 * t) + 15,
        (65 + 10 * sin(26 * t)) * cos(2 * t),
        4326)
from tally
    cross apply (select t = cast(N as float) / @cnt * pi()) p;
```

Объединим их в линию, используя конвертацию в *Gml* формат и обратно:

```
-- line from points using Gml
declare @line geography;

with xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.opengis.net/gml')
select
    @line = geography::GeomFromGml((
        select
            (
                select point.AsGml().value('(/Point/pos/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') + ' '
                from @Points
                order by num
                for xml path(''), type
            )
        for xml path('posList'), root('LineString')), 4326);
```

Через *WKB* формат (здесь пришлось прибегнуть к рекурсивному *CTE*):

```
-- line from points using WKB
declare @line geography;

with line(num, geo) as (
    select 0, cast(geography::STLineFromText('LINESTRING EMPTY', 4326).STAsBinary() as varbinary(max))
    union all
    select l.num + 1, l.geo + substring(p.point.STAsBinary(), 6, 16)
    from @Points p
        join line l on l.num + 1 = p.num
)
select top (1)
    @line = geography::STGeomFromWKB(cast(stuff(geo, 6, 4, iif(left(geo, 1) = 0x01, cast(reverse(cast(num as binary(4))) as binary(4)), cast(num as binary(4)))) as varbinary(max)), 4326)
from line
order by num desc
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Проверяем результат:

```
select @line as Line;
```

[image: geography line from points]

Comment: Спасибо, очень наглядно и понятно!